# PHP não retorna resultado do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Olá,

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function makeLogin($user, $pass) {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".HOSTNAME.";dbname=".DATABASE.";charset=utf8;", USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user, pass FROM users WHERE user = :user AND pass = :pass");
    $sql->bindParam(":user", $user);
    $sql->bindParam(":pass", $pass);
    $sql->execute();
    $users = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(count($users) <= 0) {
        return "false";
    } else {
        return "true";
    }
}
```

Caso for encontrado no banco de dados, o usuário e a senha, o PHP retorna true, caso contrário, false, mas não acha o usuário e a senha.

Estou usando o seguinte SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `user`, `pass`) VALUES
(1, 'admin', 'admin');
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
if(makeLogin($_POST['usuario'], $_POST['senha']) == 'true') {
        setcookie('logged', true,  time() + 86400);
} else {
    setcookie('logged', false,  time() + 86400);
}
```

O post é `admin` e `admin`.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: sempre retorna false?

Comment: Posta o código do `form` apenas os campos de User e Senha e também a chamada da função `makeLogin`.

Comment: Já tentou debugar as variáveis `$user` e `$pass`?

Comment: Veja se aparece algum erro com esse código: `if(!$sql->execute()){
 print_r($sql->errorInfo());
}`

Comment: em quer servidor você está executando? tem servidor que só aceita as consultas com aquele aspas simples ```SELECT `user`, `pass` FROM `users` WHERE `user` = :user AND `pass` = :pass")```

Answer (score -1):

Olha eu testei seu código aqui e funcionou.

Se estiver usando seu código no servidor de hospedagem verifique se o mesmo não está na sintaxe estilo phpmymadmin

Por exemplo, passei pelo mesmo problema um dia desses.

Minha consulta estava correta mas não trazia resultados, então eu decidi colocar aquelas aspas simples(`) e advinha? Funcionou!

Minha sugestão

Troque:

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user, pass FROM users WHERE user = :user AND pass = :pass");
```

Por:

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `user`, `pass` FROM `users` WHERE `user` = :user AND `pass` = :pass");
```